# Cloud Functions (2nd gen) and the "onCall" method: Why is "request.auth" undefined in SSR page?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

Why am I getting a `request.auth` is `undefined` in this `onCall` function?

**I am using Firebase Function emulator for this test.**

I am trying to call a Firebase function directly from my app like so:

**`/functions/getStory.js`:**

```
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'
import { error, log } from 'firebase-functions/logger'
import { onCall, HttpsError } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https'

export const getStory = onCall({ cors: true }, async (request) => {
  const db = getFirestore() // in v2, this is how you get Firestore instance

  log('request.auth from client:', request.auth)
  if (!request.auth) {
    throw new HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'Request not authenticated')
  }

  return {
    uid: request.auth.uid,
    docId: request.data.docId,
    text: 'Hello World from Server!'
  }
})
```

The above function, when invoked, responds with the following:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-getStory"
>  {"verifications":{"app":"MISSING","auth":"MISSING"},"logging.googleapis.com/labels":{"firebase-log-type":"callable-req                                                                                                                   quest-verification"},"severity":"DEBUG","message":"Callable request verification passed"}
>  {"severity":"ERROR","message":"request.auth from client: undefined"}\n    at 
i  functions: Finished "us-central1-getStory" in 3.5084ms
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-getStory"
i  functions: Finished "us-central1-getStory" in 1.4233ms
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-getStory"
>  {"verifications":{"app":"MISSING","auth":"VALID"},"logging.googleapis.com/labels":{"firebase-log-type":"callable-request-verification"},"severity":"DEBUG","message":"Callable request verification passed"}
>  {"severity":"INFO","message":"request.auth from client: kRUx8ZxLoUd0y7kTcxgPfwTiGu13"}
i  functions: Finished "us-central1-getStory" in 2.5383ms
```

Here is the client side code that invokes the cloud function:

**`/pages/test-oncall.vue`:**

```
<template>
    <section>
        {{ response }}
    </section>
</template>

<script setup>
import { httpsCallable } from 'firebase/functions'

const response = ref('')

const { functions } = useFirebase()
const instance = httpsCallable(functions, 'getStory')
try {
    response.value = await instance({ uid: 'uidTest', docId: 'docIdTest' })
    console.warn('Response ===>', response.value)
} catch (error) {
    console.log('Error ===>', error)
}


</script>
```

The browser log for the above client code is:

```
Error ===> [FirebaseError: INTERNAL] {
  code: 'functions/internal',
  customData: undefined,
  details: undefined
}
```

Notice that the `request.auth` is `undefined` at an initial `log` point (`"message":"request.auth from client: undefined"}`, but then later resolves correctly. Why does this happen? It's like auth is not initialized yet until a later time. If that's the case, **how do I properly check `request.auth` so I can do some authentication on the server to determine if the user is eligible to receive confidential data from Firestore when using the `onCall` method?**

Comment: @DougStevenson , I am using server side rendering (SSR) on the page that invokes the httpsCallable. That is probably why.

Comment: Then you definitely won't get an auth property as explained in my answer.  A user can't be signed into a backend.  It's a frontend only operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of an `auth` property suggests that there was no user signed in at the time the function was invoked from the frontend.

See the example from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#handle_errors):

```
// Checking that the user is authenticated.
if (!request.auth) {
  // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
  throw new HttpsError("failed-precondition", "The function must be " +
          "called while authenticated.");
}
```

Users are not signed in immediately on page load.  You must use an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to know when the user data is fully validated and ready for use (this includes callable functions).